# How to add a namespace to XML output in PLSQL

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle10g

let's suppose to have the following table:

```
create table mytable
(name       varchar2(10),
 surname    varchar2(10));
```

If I run this query:

```
select xmlelement("person",
           xmlelement("first_name",t.name).extract('/*'),
           xmlelement("second_name",t.surname).extract('/*')
           ).extract('/*')
from mytable t;
```

I get:

```
<person>
  <first_name>John</first_name>
  <second_name>Brown</second_name>
</person>
```

but how can I get something like this

```
<ns1:person xmlns:ns1="Schemas">
  <ns1:first_name>John</ns1:first_name>
  <ns1:second_name>Brown</ns1:second_name>
</ns1:person>
```

Oracle version 10g

Thanks!

Mark

Answer (score 0):

You can add the namespace declaration as an attribute, and modify your identifiers to specify it:

```
select xmlelement("ns1:person",
           xmlattributes('Schemas' as "xmlns:ns1"),
           xmlelement("ns1:first_name",t.name).extract('/*'),
           xmlelement("ns1:second_name",t.surname).extract('/*')
           ).extract('/*')
from mytable t;
```

which gets:

```xml
<ns1:person xmlns:ns1="Schemas"><ns1:first_name>John</ns1:first_name><ns1:second_name>Brown</ns1:second_name></ns1:person>
```

or serialized to format it for display:

```xml
<ns1:person xmlns:ns1="Schemas">
  <ns1:first_name>John</ns1:first_name>
  <ns1:second_name>Brown</ns1:second_name>
</ns1:person>
```

The `extract()` isn't really adding anything though; if you want it as a string then `getstringval` or `getclobval` is probably cleaner.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ee12d560182875bffbc343dd13ee4c2b)

---

OK, it seems like maybe `extract()` is formatting it nicely in 10g, but it doesn't in 11g; and 10g also did support `indent` for XMLSerialize. If it doesn't like `.extract('/*')` then it might be unhappy with the namespaces; it might work with `.extract('/')` instead, in all three places that's used.

Comment: Thank you but with XMLATTRIBUTES I see that .extract('/*') gets error and if I don't put .extract('/*') I get all on the same line. How can I have every tag on different line? I can't use XMLSERIALIZE because I work on Oracle 10g

Comment: The extract doesn't error in the db<>fiddle, though that is 11g not 10g. But like I said you don't need it; it leaves everything on one line anyway? And I've shown XMLSerialize to format it into multiple lines. Oh... [in 10g](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14259/xdb13gen.htm#CHDDIHBH) that didn't have the `indent` option. And looks like maybe extract used to format but doesn't now? Strange. What error does it give - maybe wants to handle namespaces? Does `.extract('/')` work?

Comment: Ok but the problem is that in 10g XMLSERIALIZE doesn't work and I'd like to have the XML well-ordered for a pure extetic reason
If I run the first query you wrote I get ORA-31011: XML parsing failed